# Google Picker not working in Sidebar Add On

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using Google Picker from an Add On Sidebar. I pretty much used all the code provided in the picker tutorial and it worked very well.

However, when the Picker modal dialog displays it is limited to the dimensions of the Add On Side bar. Making it unusable. I would expect it to be limited to the dimensions of the Google Document window (which my sidebar is attached to). Here is the main code:

```
function createPicker(token) { 
    if (pickerApiLoaded && token) {

      var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
          // Instruct Picker to display only spreadsheets in Drive. For other
          // views, see https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#otherviews
          .addView(google.picker.ViewId.SPREADSHEETS)
          // Hide the navigation panel so that Picker fills more of the dialog.
          .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
          // Hide the title bar since an Apps Script dialog already has a title.
          .hideTitleBar()
          .setOAuthToken(token)
          .setDeveloperKey(DEVELOPER_KEY)
          .setCallback(pickerCallback)
          // Instruct Picker to fill the dialog, minus 2 pixels for the border.
          .setSize(DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.width - 2,
              DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.height - 2)
           .build();

      //picker.setOrigin(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host);     


      picker.setVisible(true);

    } else {
      showError('Unable to load the file picker.');
    }
  }
```

I was thinking that the following setOrgin() might help. But it actually prevents the picker from working.

```
setOrigin(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the origin to docs.google.com.

```
            .setOrigin('https://docs.google.com')
```

Comment: Yes have tried that with no success. Have made sure I am using "docs" in Docs and "sheets" in Sheets. But as I say above, it actually prevents it from even showing when I do this making it even worse.